# No access to serial ports. Try loading as a Chrome Application

Tags: angular, serial-port

We want to serial port communication using angular2 project.

angular2, browser-serialport.
Installed following

```
import * as SerialPort  from 'browser-serialport';
```

and

```
SerialPort.list(function(err, ports) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(ports);
        });
```

got following errors

```
Error: No access to serial ports. Try loading as a Chrome Application.
    at Object.SerialPortList [as list] (index.js:385) [angular]...
```

when use

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", {
            baudrate: 57600
        }, false);
```

then errors

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11_browser_serialport__ is not a constructor
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11_browser_serialport__ is not a constructor
```

Comment: Did you read this?: https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-serialport#restrictions

Comment: yes, this is right way to create chrome app?

Comment: An Angular app is not a [Chrome Application](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app).